# DrawingCache strange behavior with Motorola devices

Tags: c#, java, android, bitmap, xamarin.android

I'm having a strange issue on some Motorola devices where I'm getting a `Bitmap` that's cropped and scaled inside of an `ImageView`.  This is programmed in mono for android 4.2.4.

Basically my issue is `DrawingCache` is returning null on some devices, namely Motorola devices.  I've searched around for solutions to this and none of the method's suggested have worked.  I just don't really understand why this work on some devices and not on others?

I'm able to pull out the entire image by using `ImageView.Drawable`, but that lacks all the manipulations done to it, so this is not really desired.

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening or possible work arounds?

```
        try
        {
            //pictureView is an ImageView
            pictureView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
            using (var bmp = pictureView.DrawingCache)
            {
                if (bmp != null)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _pictureView.DrawingCacheEnabled = false;
        }
```

Our app is written with Mono for Android, but Java answers are welcome.

Update: I created an android application to display the problems I'm having. The open source project I'm using is [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) to allow the user to zoom in on an image. Using the Motorola emulator fails to display the bitmap, while the x86 emulator worked correctly in display the bitmap.

```
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button mButton;
TouchImageView mImage;
ImageView mImageView;
Bitmap mBmp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snoopy);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mImage = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    mImage.setImageBitmap(snoop);
    mImage.setMaxZoom(4f);

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == mButton.getId())
    {
        try
        {
            mImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            mBmp = mImage.getDrawingCache(false);

            if(mBmp != null && !mBmp.isRecycled())
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "BITMAP NOT NULL! ZOMG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBmp);
                mImageView.invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "BITMAP IS NULL! BOOO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Log.e("Test", exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}